# Can we always find $f_1$ and $f_2$ in $F$ such that $\lVert f_1 \rVert= \lVert f_2 \rVert=1$ and $\lVert f_1 + f_2 \rVert=2$

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $F$ be a normed linear space with a norm that is not strictly convex. Is it true then that we can always find different $f_1$ and $f_2$ in $F$ such that $\lVert f_1 \rVert= \lVert f_2 \rVert=1$ and $\lVert f_1 + f_2 \rVert=2$. Ofcourse, when $F$ is not just the space containing only the zero element.

Comment: Who are the functions f?

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictly_convex_space Is $F$ complete?

Comment: No , $F$ is a general non strict convex space

Answer (score 4):

As $\|\cdot\|$ is not strictly convex, there exist distinct points $f_1,f_2$ on the unit sphere such that some convex combination $tf_1+(1-t)f_2$, $0<t<1$, of them is not an interior point of the unit ball. By convexity of the ball, $\|f_1\|=\|f_2\|=\|tf_1+(1-t)f_2\|=1$. In fact this implies (using convexity again) that  $\|uf_1+(1-u)f_2\|=1$ for all $u\in[0,1]$.
In particular $\|\frac12 f_1+\frac12f_2\|=1$ as desired.

Comment: I can follow until the last implication. Trying to prove that statement but can't get anywhere. My approach is using the result of the answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2094821/467442